# Ember keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, ember.js, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an ember application to which I want to add keyboard shortcuts. A specific key combination should work regardless of where the user is within the app, that is, the key press should trigger an action regardless of the controller, view or the route within which the user is at any point. In order to do this, I will have to listen to `keyPress` event in my app. I tried using a mixin that will be mixed in to the `ApplicationView`, unfortunately, the `keyPress` event will only be propagated if a view has focus and application view will not always have focus. I tried:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend(App.KeyBoardShortcutsMixin,{
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().focus();
  } 
});
```

This will not accomplish my purpose because, the `keyPress` event works fine before the user interacts with the app, but once this view loses focus, it will no longer fire. Since I have a large number of views, it seems wasteful to mixin the view mixin into every single view that might be created in the app. How can I add this functionality in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do with your shortcuts, but if you bind the keypress event to the body of the application, the event should be triggered whatever has the focus

```
Ember.$('body').on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log('do something');
});
```

Here is an illustration with the "enter key" : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zukazazo/2/edit

Once again, without more details about what you are trying to accomplish in your mixin, it's hard to answer you question.

Comment: I could do this of course, but I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic way of accomplishing the same within ember? without resorting to jquery. What I want to do in my mixin is to send an action to the currently active controller and let the controller handle the action.

Comment: Never heard of built-in event listener at the page level... You will have to use $('body') or $(document) to listen to your event or manually trigger focus on your view if you still want to use the built-in keypress view hook.

Comment: The idiomatic way of doing this is to add the event handler `keyPress` to the view. See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names. I expect the event would bubble up, but YMMV. You may want to try putting the handler inside a `eventManager` hash on the app view.